# Confirmation box in jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Can we make confirmation box same as delete in jqgrid for doing any other operation in jqgrid. What changes we need to do in classes or html so that the look and feel should be the same as delete confirmation box.

Comment: Please specify more exact what you mean under "confirmation box". Which "confirmation box" you want to replace? It's important additionally to know which **version** of jqGrid you use (can use) and from which **fork** of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7).

Comment: Confirmation box as in when we click on delete button it shows confirmation box which gives option delete and ok. I want to use same box with different functionality.I use free jqgrid

Comment: Please, answer **which version** of free jqGrid you use (can use)? It's really important to know. jqGrid has own dialog methods, which do more as "confirmation box". If you examine "Delete" dialog more exactly you will see two buttons with custom icons and custom text. the Dialog contains custom HTML text and so on. There are exist simplified method `$.jgrid.info_dialog` which I suppose you need. What kind of dialog with wich information you need to display? **Which button(s) you need in the dialog?**. I can post you short example of usage it I know the version of jqGrid.

Comment: I am using 4.7 . I want two buttons same as delete box as Yes and No .As you said $.jgrid.info_dialog it provides only info options (close).But I want confirmation box same as delete but the options should be Yes and No

Comment: jqGrid 4.7 is published at the end of 2014. It's not more supported. It was the last version of the product "jqGrid". After that Tony Tomov renamed the product to "Guriddo jqGrid JS" and made it commercial available under [the prices](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334). After that, also at the end of 2014, I started the fork of the old jqGrid 4.7 under the name "free jqGrid" (see [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/) and [here](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html)) where I implemented a lot of new features holding compatibility with jqGrid 4.7.

Comment: I recommend you to upgrade either to free jqGrid 4.15.4 or to Guriddo jqGrid JS 5.3.1. jqGrid 4.7 is not more supported.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the method `$.jgrid.info_dialog`. The code could be the following

```
$.jgrid.info_dialog.call($grid[0],
    "Confirmation",         // dialog title
    "Are <b>you</b> sure?", // any HTML code of the content of the dialog
    "",
    {
        buttons: [
            {
                id: "my_yes",
                text: "Yes",
                onClick: function (e, $dlg) {
                    alert("Yes is clicked");
                }
            },
            {
                id: "my_no",
                text: "No",
                onClick: function (e, $dlg) {
                    alert("No is clicked");
                }
            }
        ]
    });
```

where `$grid` is a variable initialized like `var $grid = $("#youGridId");`. The resulting dialog looks like on the picture below:

[image]

Comment: Can you also show how to remove the dialog when clicking Yes or No? Clicking the buttons doesn't close the dialog and neither does `$dlg.dialog('destroy');`

Comment: Also, the dialog does not behave like other jqgrid dialogs (Different alignment for text and buttons, different position relative to the grid). How can we make it look more like original jqgrid dialogs?